# Nginx proxy_cache / Varnish - parallel requests trigger multiple requests to backend?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish

I am looking for a HTTP reverse proxy that will handle HTTP live streaming use cases in a performant manner. Assume file/fragment sizes up to 4MB with a constant load of client requests for the same file, very close together (requests arriving while backend is satisfying the first request).

CDN services will not be used here.

What happens in the events below for each Nginx and Varnish (please insert another solution you believe is more appropriate as well)?

1. Client1 makes request to reverse proxy (proxy_cache or Varnish), file is not cached (MISS).
2. Proxy makes requests to backend and attempts to fill local cache and deliver response to Client1
3. While the the request for Client1 is being serviced (before proxy completes), other concurrent requests for same file are made by other clients.

The goal is:

1. Proxy will block additional requests while it retrieves file from backend.
2. Proxy will serve all waiting clients concurrently as the data arrives (as it arrives, not after the entire file is buffered).
3. Only one request to backend will ever be made at any given time, for a specific file.  All clients should be serviced by the shared response from the backend.  The exception is if client makes a HTTP range request for a different range of course.

Which solution is best when larger files are being requested like this?  If there are any key configuration settings to achieve the desired result, please share.

Thank you!